# R-Shiny is breaking down by using dcast from data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a odd problem by using `shinydashboard` on the server. Shiny is breaking down (`1: shiny::runApp` my guess:cannot run the app again) if the code dose not find data in one place. I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in dcast.data.table: Can not cast an empty data.table
  118: stop
  117: dcast.data.table
  115: <reactive:scrdata> [C:\scrBUG/server.R#106]
   99: scrdata
   95: func
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$plotscr
    1: shiny::runApp
```

The code is to big to be shown here. However, the position where I use `dcast` is

```
dataset <- reactive({
        # apply Filter    
data<- data[(mmoSzenario %in% user.liste)]
.
.
.       data<-data[,list('wrt.'=sum(as.numeric(wrt))),by=list(gesell,mmoSzenario)]
data<- dcast(data, gesell ~ mmoSzenario , value.var='wrt.')
...
```

any idea how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that no `mmoSzenario` where within `user.liste`?

Answer (score 2):

the issue is a `reshape2` / `data.table` design choice, find the explanation [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1215).

You can work around it easily with an if clause:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(gesell = character(),mmoSzenario = character(),wrt. = integer())
# this creates your error
data<- dcast(data, gesell ~ mmoSzenario , value.var='wrt.')

# simple workaround
if(data[,.N]>0){
  data<- dcast(data, gesell ~ mmoSzenario , value.var='wrt.')
} else {
  # choose the format of your expected output
}
```

If your issue affects the front-end I recommend you using `shiny`'s [validation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html).